# I need to return ALL records from Left Table Even if record doesnt exist in where clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

Hello I have two tables (Inventory and Sales).

I am trying to get a current view of inventory with total sales within a given date range by SKU, where SKU is available in both tables. I also want the SKU to be returned even if there were no sales during the date range (if it doesn't exist in the where clause).

I have tried to use the "Between" date where clause, but that is only returning the SKUs that were sold during the week. I also want to include the SKUs that were NOT sold during the week, and they should have 0 values for Sales $ and Qty Ordered.

I have tried experimenting with EXIST clause but have not been successful.

Here is my query:

```
SELECT Inventory.SKU, Sum([Sales].[Sales $]), Inventory.Qty, Sum([Sales].Qty Ordered)
FROM Inventory LEFT JOIN Sales ON Inventory.SKU = [Sales].[Style Id]
WHERE ((([Sales].[Order date]) Between #5/14/2016# And #5/22/2016#))
GROUP BY Inventory.SKU, Inventory.Qty;
```

Comment: All you have to do is move the content of the where clause to the on clause.

Comment: I've added the MS-Access tag for you. With SQL queries you should always tag your DBMS - especially when it's MS-Access, which is so little standard compliant!

Answer (score 3):

Criteria on an outer joined table belongs in the ON clause:

```
SELECT 
  Inventory.SKU, 
  Sum(Sales.[Sales $]), 
  Inventory.Qty, 
  Sum(Sales.[Qty Ordered])
FROM (Inventory 
LEFT JOIN Sales ON Inventory.SKU = Sales.[Style Id]
                AND Sales.[Order date] Between #5/14/2016# And #5/22/2016#)
GROUP BY Inventory.SKU, Inventory.Qty;
```

The reason is that to outer join means to join a dummy record filled with NULLs in case no record matches. But with the columns being NULL, the `WHERE` criteria will never be true for these records and you are where you were with a simple `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: Thanks - when I change the WHERE to AND I get MS Access error "JOIN Expression Not Supported"

Comment: Hm, I don't know. Fortunately I don't have to work with MS Access. I remember I had to use parentheses that seemed superfluous, last time I did. That was with multiple joins though. Well, I'll edit, you try :-)

Answer (score 1):

All you have to do is move the content of the where clause to the on clause:

```
SELECT Inventory.SKU, Sum([Sales].[Sales $]), Inventory.Qty, Sum([Sales].Qty Ordered)
FROM Inventory 
LEFT JOIN Sales ON  ((Inventory.SKU = [Sales].[Style Id]) 
                AND (([Sales].[Order date] Between #5/14/2016# And #5/22/2016#)))
GROUP BY Inventory.SKU, Inventory.Qty;
```

Comment: Thanks - when I change the WHERE to AND I get MS Access error "JOIN Expression Not Supported"

Comment: I didn't work with MS Access the last decade or so, but if memory serves, it does like parenthesis. Try my edited answer.